# Is it possible to add a gif in a canvas buffer in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, canvas, discord.js

The answer is yes, the problem is how?

This is not for a website, this is for a discord bot that fully coded using nodejs.

Some users have animated profile pictures of various sizes and legth and i would like to take those animated profile pictures and put them inside of an already existing image, i tried various packages and could not find anything that fits my needs, so i am resorting to the knowledgeable kind people of stackoverflow.

(I apologize if i'm making spelling mistakes, my english is far from perfect)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a users profile picture with [discordjs#displayerAvatarURL](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL). If you then checkout [discordjs#ImageURLOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions) you can see the solution to your question is using `memberObject.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })`

To use it inside of an embed:

```
new MessageEmbed().setThumbnail(memberObject.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }) || memberObject.user.defaultAvatarURL)
```

^ Notice the fallback to `memberObject.user.defaultAvatarURL`, if you wouldn't do this you'd receive an error whenever trying to load a dynamic profile picture while they never changed it, meaning it's a default Discord picture.

Of course, #setImage can be used instead of #setThumbnail; you're just applying the dynamic image to a different part of the embed.

Comment: The OP asks how to add gifs to a canvas buffer, this would nothing but return the animated profile picture but show up as static in the final buffer, please consider imporving your answer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me, but this is unfortunately not what i asked, i should've been more clear i apologize.